# ¿Cómo tener un group_indicator que no cambie de tamaño en un ExpandableListView?

Tags: android

Tengo un archivo **group_indicator.xml** el cual lo uso para personalizar el groupIndicator de un ExpandableList:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_keyboard_arrow_down_24px"
        android:state_expanded="true"/>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_keyboard_arrow_up_24px"/>
</selector>
```

Este es el layout que contiene el ExpandableListView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/navre"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <ExpandableListView
                android:id="@+id/expandableListObjectives"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:divider="@color/gris_sunglo"
                android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
                android:groupIndicator="@drawable/expandable_indicator"
                android:indicatorLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemIndicatorLeft" />
</LinearLayout>
```

El problema es que la altura del icono cambia de acuerdo al número de líneas te texto que tiene el GroupView.
Cómo se puede ver el primer groupIndicator se ve más grande. Sin embargo el groupIndicator que trae por default se mantiene siempre del mismo tamaño.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La imagen que defines como indicador del grupo siempre estará tomando la altura que tenga el grupo de acuerdo a su texto, en este caso te sugiero usar como imagen un `selector`..

Crea el archivo `my_group_indicator.xml` dentro del directorio `/drawable` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_empty="true">
        <layer-list>
            <item
                android:left="0dp"
                android:right="5dp"
                android:top="25dp"
                android:bottom="25dp"
                android:drawable="@drawable/expandable_indicator">
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>

    <item android:state_expanded="true">
        <layer-list>
            <item
                android:left="0dp"
                android:right="2dp"
                android:top="25dp"
                android:bottom="25dp"
                android:drawable="@drawable/expandable_indicator">
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>

</selector>
```

y usa este archivo como imagen:

```
android:groupIndicator="@drawable/my_group_indicator"
```